# Drop down change event populate value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Table

```
Id(Key)  Description(Value)             Car

1         scott                         BMW

2         john                          ford
```

Id and Description will be Key value pair to Dropdown. I have to display Car name in textbox based on the Id selected.

What will be the best way to achieve this.

Is there a way to avoid call to server for every dropdown event change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store "Car" as a custom client-side attribute of `ListItem` element of the dropdown (it will become an attribute of `<option>` element when list item is rendered.

On client-side on `onchange` event you can retrieve that attribute and display it in the textbox.